# php function to check if number is divisible by 0

Tags: php, math

I have checked a bunch of posts on stackoverflow and on articles on google but none of them were able to answer my question. Here is my code (i've simplified it instead of posting my code)

```
$first = 10;
$second = 0; //comes from db row count
$total = !is_int($first/$second) ? 0 : $first/$second;
```

problem is when i do this I keep getting the Division by zero error. I have a bunch and $second isnt always 0, it can be any number. But it does come out to 0 since the row counts for whatever query it comes out as 0. Is there a safe way of checking to see if $first can be divided by $second without giving an error? I have tried @ before the !is_int and that just breaks all other statements.

Comment: Nothing is divisible by zero. You need to check if `second` is zero. If so, don't divide by it and do a defult action instead.

Comment: why dont you just check to make sure $second is greater than 0?

Comment: you're dividing by zero, and wondering why you get a divide by zero error? supressing a division by zero error just moves the error farther down the line.

Comment: Easy! `function isDivisibleByZero($value) { return false; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't divide by 0 it is undefined. If you want to handle division by 0 just check if the divisor isn't equals to 0. Or a safer way, chack if it is a positive integer:

```
$first = 10;
$dbRowCount = dbFunction();
if ($dbRowCount > 0) {
    $total = $first / $dbRowCount;
} else {
    //Error handling
}
```

Comment: thing is what i'm trying to do is if its not divisible by zero then the value = 0 . this is a value that i need to get in return.

Comment: @SarmenHB Stuff will never be divisible by zero... So in that case you doesn't even need a condition, just assing `0`.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$total = ($second == 0) ? 0 : $first / $second;
```

Comment: Mathematically speaking, as the divisor approaches zero the result approaches infinity. If any actual math is being performed with these values then returning zero would invalidate the ultimate result of subsequent operations.

Comment: Missed my edit window. PHP has two constants for cases like these, `INF` and `NAN`, both of which are floats representing infinity and 'Not a Number' respectively.

Comment: That's a valid point. I was just fixing his line of code, assuming that he wanted the total to be zero in this case. +1'd

Answer (score 0):

The ternary structure can accept more than one condition. and it will work just as any other `if` condition, and won't try the second condition if the first fails.

So, just add it

```
$total = ($first!==0 && $second!==0 && !is_int($first/$second)) ? 0 : $first/$second;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try checking if your $Second variable is 0.

Something like:

```
$First = 10;
$Second = $row['table_column'];

if ($Second == 0) {
echo "Oops this will be an error";
}
else
$First/$second = $me;
```